# Application Design - Pop up authentication with MVVM

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light, application-design

This questions is not really about code but application design.
I have an app that needs authentication, to do that I have a pop up that appears on the main page when the user is not logged in.

My question is how to make this right, following the mvvm pattern. I think that the popup control should be in the code behind of the view, but who sends the order to show it? The view model or the model? Should the code behind check with the viewmodel if the user is authenticated (I don't think that this is the correct aproach) ?

I've been studying the mvvm pattern and started to use mvvm light as a simple and clean way to separate the business from the presentation layer.

This problem was the first that I couldn't figure it out by myself.

Thanks

Comment: Most people solve this kind of problem with behaviours which are of course some kind of do-codebehind-without-anyone-noticing hack - to make this short: be pragmatic and use the codebehind if every other solution seems to be to much trouble - I think this is ok here ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig use code-behind in what way? Ask the viewmodel if it should authenticate? That just seams wrong xDD. I understand your point very well, we shouldn't complicate something simple just to make it pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this. With the DataContext of the UserControl set to the current user:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding Path=User}">
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsAuthenticated, Converter={StaticResource BoolToOpposite}">
  ...
</Popup>
</Control>
```

You might have to read up on Converters or call the Property IsNotAuthenticated to move forward quicker.

Comment: That seams to be a good solution, shame on me not seeing that property, the other data on the viewmodel should be null since the user is not authenticated. That is a viable and pretty solution ;). Thanks

Comment: you are very welcome. good luck with the mvvm, it requires some getting used to...

Comment: of course that "pollutes" your View with something it should not do (display the authentication) - so this vertical-concern might have to be repeated in every view ... this is why I would show another view for authentication and then you cannot just bind but has to implement some kind of navigation-framework (AFAIK there is no such thing in MVVM light and it's mostly done with messages)